# how to download a package with python-apt?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, debian, apt

I want to know as title says: how to download a package using python-apt API? Only download it, don't to install it, just like does the command:

```
apt-get download ${package_name}
```

I'm using python v2.7.5-5ubuntu3 with python-apt v0.9.3.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import apt
import os, sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'Usage: apt-download pkg_name'
    sys.exit()

cache = apt.Cache()
pkg   = cache[sys.argv[1]]
cmd   = 'wget ' + pkg.candidate.uri
print cmd
os.system(cmd)
```

It works well with Python 2.7.8 and python-apt 0.9.3.11 but it should also work with your configuration.